# Immediately Invoking Methods with Javascript Bind

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about Bind, Call, and Apply, and I have a question about Bind that I haven't been able to find a good response for it:

Say I have the following code

```
var Jim = {
    firstName: 'Jim',
    lastName: 'Bob',
    fullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; 
    }
};

var fName = Jim.fullName; //now fName's context is window

//If I invoke fName here, I will get the expected 'undefined undefined' 
console.log(fName());
```

I can, however, also do the following and get my bound method to invoke immediately after passing a new context:

```
fName.bind(Jim)(); //this returns 'Jim Bob'
```

I feel like this is just mimicking what can (should?) be done with `call` or `apply`. If I invoke `fName()` again after the previous line, It is still bound to the window object (fName was not modified by the in place use of bind). Is this bad practice?

How about this though:

```
var Jim = {
    //same object definition as above
};

var Chris = {
    firstName: 'Chris',
    lastName: 'Smith'
};

var fName = Jim.fullName.bind(Jim); //now fName's context is the Jim object
console.log(fName()); //this will log 'Jim Bob' as expected
```

And NOW if I try to bind the bound method to another context in place, it does not work:

```
fName.bind(Chris)(); //this still logs 'Jim Bob' from the original context
```

I believe in this second case this is because I'm basically creating a "function bound bound", so it has two contexts and just goes for the first one.

Any thoughts on either of these cases?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: If a second `bind` could change the `this` value, it would mean the first `bind` didn't bound it.

Comment: *"now fName's context is window"* - No it isn't. The context is set each time the function is *called*, not each time you create a reference to it. fName and Jim.fullName are references to the same function. Regarding .bind(), they're is no point calling it only to immediately invoke the function it returns - as you kind of said you might as well use .call() or .apply() for that. The point of .bind() is to create a function that you can call at some other point, so to use it sensibly you'd assign the returned function to a variable, or pass it as an argument to some other function.

Comment: ^nnnnnn that is a good point. the context is NOT window. The context is just not defined until the method is invoked (defaulting to the object in which it is invoked, which, in the case of invoking it globally, is window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially right all across the board. Doing

```
var fName = Jim.fullName;
fName.bind(Jim)();
```

Is the exact same thing as

```
var fName = Jim.fullName;
fName.call(Jim);
```

I'm not sure I'd call the first example "bad practice" but it's definitely not "good practice." `call` does exactly what you want without generating a new function value and (in my opinion) better describes your intent.

As for why you can't rebind a function, you're very close to right. Rather than there being two contexts for `fName`, it still only has the one. But `bind` explicitly states "this is the context of this function, no question about it."

Answer (score 0):

You are no longer binding to same fName function as before. `bind` returns a new bound function whose `this` value cannot be overridden.

As per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind),

> The bind() function creates a **new function** (a bound function) with the same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), which **cannot be overridden**.

Comment: I didn't see this part of the documentation! The cannot be overridden part is pretty clear :) Thanks for your response.